# detecting and disabling autocompletion on mobile devices with either complete.ly or typeahead

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typeahead.js, complete.ly

In my project I want to use either

- complete.ly (see http://complete-ly.appspot.com )
- or typeahead.js (see http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

As far as I know, none of the two libraries support mobile devices so I need to handle that. 
As far as typeahead goes they have an issue that they said they are not going to fix https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/324

Although I expect a very small number of users using a mobile device (my web app is some kinda dashboard and not really suitable on small screens) I would like to be able to detect that case and at least being able to give them a standard HTML input text.

Any suggestions ?

Particularly for complete.ly

Comment: Use screen size to detect?

Answer (score 2):

First you should find a way to determine if you are running on the mobile or not.

see: [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser)

For complete.ly you could do something like this:

```
if (typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') { 
    // mobile.
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text'
    ...
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(input);
    ... 
} else {
    var completely = document.getElementById('container'); 
    ...
    ...
}
```

arguably this could be handled by complete.ly itself.